# Is there a way to pass a form #value to the form #action in Drupal 7 form API?

Tags: forms, actions

In the example below I want to take elements from the form and include them as part of the URL that I am submitting the form (using #action) so the submitted URL would look like http://example.com/name_storage/John/Lewis/123412341234.

```
    <?php


function my_module_menu() {
  $items[‘testform’] = array(
    'title' => 'First Last Name',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('my_module_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
  return $items;
}

function my_module_form($form,&$form_submit) {
  $form[‘first_name’] = array(
    '#title' => t(The first name of the person),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form[‘last_name’] = array(
    '#title' => t('The first name of the person'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['passcode'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Passcode for this domain.'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#value' => '123412341234',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#value' => ‘Submit,
    '#type' => 'submit',
    );
  $form['#action'] = url('http://example.com/name_storage/' . $form['first_name']['#value'] . '/'. $form['first_name']['#value'] . '/' . $form['passcode']['#value']);
  return $form;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In FAPI, #action changes the form's action parameter, which, you should not override if you want to make Drupal handle the submission.

In your case, you need to define a custom submit handler and redirect the user in that function. You could do something similar by changing the form's method to GET, but it is not possible to define a complex path like the one you want.

Remove this line:

```
$form['#action'] = url('http://example.com/name_storage/' . $form['first_name']['#value'] . '/'. $form['first_name']['#value'] . '/' . $form['passcode']['#value']);
```

Then, add a new submit handler like this:

```
function my_module_form_submit($form,&$form_state) {
  $values = $form_state['values']['first_name'] . '/'. $form_state['values']['last_name'] . '/' . $form_state['values']['passcode'];
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'name_storage/' . $values;
}
```

To set the redirect parameter to an external URL, you can do this:

```
$values = 'http://example.com/name_storage/';
$values .= $form_state['values']['first_name'] . '/'. $form_state['values']['last_name'] . '/' . $form_state['values']['passcode'];
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  $values,
  array(
    'external' => TRUE,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Great, now how do I get it to submit to an external domain (in this it's going to example.com instead of the drupal site itself)?

Comment: Just change the `$form_state['redirect']` to whatever URL you need. The example in the answer is for internal links but you still can put any URL there.

Comment: Oddly, if I put http://example.com in front, I get an error where it appears that apache (MAMP) is url decoding the url encoded string I used for the values... I see the URL in the redirected URL as encoded, but it's treating the encoded %252F is getting decoded as /'s and I'm not sure why (obviously results in error). Only when I add the domain to the front, however.

Comment: @JohnLewis See the updated answer.